# RSA Archer Field Error: A parameter expected to be a single value was multiple values

Tags: rsa-archer-grc

Working ith RSA Archer for a while now, but now I ran into an issue I cant't seem to find a solution for.

I have a calculaed field that will reference one other field and get the e-mail address of that contact field. Yet in some records, this field has been set twice ergo it is multiple values so the calculated field returns the error:

> A parameter expected to be a single value was multiple values.

Is there a way to take either the first found value or just take BOTH values of the referenced field?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that the MOSTRECENTVALUE() calculation works well. It obviously only grabs the most recent value from a Cross Reference, so if you're most recent value is not what you're expecting this is not for you. I've also found some documentation detailing a COMBINESELECTIONS function, but it appears to only work with values lists. **I'll provide a screenshot of what I found in another answer.**

**MOSTRECENTVALUE()**

Here's the syntax along with a description, taken directly from the Formula Builder:
[Formula Builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKetk.png)

Here's the calculation in action (We can expect this to show the most recent tracking ID, based off the first published date):
[Calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdyRu.png)

**I'll have to do another answer to show the results, since I have less than 10 reputation I'm limited to 2 links and can't embed images.**

Answer (score 0):

**MOSTRECENTVALUE()**

Results [Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Clw5x.png)

**COMBINESELECTIONS**

This appears to be an upgrade included in 5.5SP2, but when trying to view details in the Formula Builder it shows a 404. I've found the following in the RSA Archer GRC Platform 5.5 and Later Release Notes.pdf. This is easily available on the RSA Community.

[CombineSelections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ln3w.png)